# Refresh just chats in a static page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a simple chat app that has a main page and then has a section on that page called `chats`. All messages are posted via a text area to `messages.html` using PHP and then fetched with `echo file_get_contents`.

```html
<div id="messages" class="messages">
<p class="systemnotice center">There are no more messages to load</p>
<br>
<div class="chats"><?php echo file_get_contents("./messages.html") ; ?></div>
</div>
```

At the moment I'm refreshing the entire page every 5 seconds to check for new messages. New messages are automatically checked after each message is "sent", they're posted with `send.php` which also sends the user back to the inbox.

I'm using the following script to scroll the messages to the bottom of the page and to refresh the page every 5 seconds.

```js
 var myTimer = setInterval('window.location.reload()', 5000);
 $('#message').on('keyup change', function(){
    if( $(this).val().length == '' ) {
        myTimer = setInterval('window.location.reload()', 5000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
 });  

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var messages = document.querySelector('#messages');
  messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight;
});
```

Is there a way to instead just refresh `div id="messages"` or use `?php echo file_get_contents("./messages.html") ; ?>` and get the contents every 5 seconds, or less given the whole page won't need to refresh, just the messages.

Any help/workable snippets would be appreciated because the rest of it works, it's just a little inconvenient always refreshing the whole page given at the moment it refreshes unless you're typing.

Thanks in advance :)

`UPDATE`

```js
var myTimer = setInterval('window.location.reload()', 5000);
 $('#message').on('keyup change', function(){
    if( $(this).val().length == '' ) {
        myTimer = setInterval('window.location.reload()', 5000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
 }); 

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var messages = document.querySelector('#messages');
  messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight;
});
```

```css
.messages {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 1.5vh;
    padding-bottom: 1.5vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="chat-header chat-hidden">
<a href="/"><img class="logo" src="./logo.png" alt="Logo"> </a>
</div>
<br>
<div id="messages" class="messages">
<p class="subheading center">There are no more messages to load</p>
<br>
<div class="chats"><?php echo file_get_contents("./messages.html") ; ?></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="messagebox">
<div class="messagefunction">
<div class="compose">
<form method="post" name="send.php" action="send.php">
<textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4" cols="60" placeholder="Compose a message." maxlength="500" autofocus required></textarea>
</div>
<div class="send">
<button type="submit" class="send-button">Send Icon Goes Here</p></button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br><br>


</script>
</body>
```

I've updated the question with a bare bones version of the messages page. I need just the `messages` DIV to reload, and not the whole page. I also need the messages DIV to scroll to the bottom on load to display the newest messages.

At the moment this;

```js
var myTimer = setInterval('window.location.reload()', 5000);
 $('#message').on('keyup change', function(){
    if( $(this).val().length == '' ) {
        myTimer = setInterval('window.location.reload()', 5000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
 });
```

refreshes the page every 5 seconds unless the user is typing a message. I'd like to replace this to refresh the DIV every 5 seconds or get the PHP again.

It's just the DIV that I want to reload, it could also only reload when the `messages.html` has an update. It reloads anyway when a message is sent so it's only an issue fetching messages from the other person. I'm open to suggestions though and the messaging page is text only now.

Comment: you can get it with ajax, and set the return data into the `#messages` div

Comment: I really don't know how to use ajax. A sample answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: just put the `Doc-Han`s code instead the `location.reload`. it will load the content from the `messages.html` to the `#messages` div without refreshing the page

Comment: That's actually worse than my initial solution, the whole page still reloads but the messages don't scroll to the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Try this ajax, it will work:-

```
function getMessage(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "page.php",//here your url to your page
    async: false,
    success: function(response){
    $('.chats').html(response); //if you want to replace html use this.
    //here you can use by id also like:- $('#messages').html(response);
    $('.chats').append(response);//if you want to append html then use this.
    setTimeout(function(){getMessage();}, 5000);
    },
    error: function(errormsg){
     console.log(errormsg);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: above ajax code will work and also like your requirement it will not refresh whole page, it will not refresh your div also. it get your data at every 5 second and just replace or append to your message div and like you said you have to $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#yourDiv").offset().top
    }, 2000); this code to scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the interval first instead of re-running it again, because two individual intervals will run, modify the code like this:

```
var myTimer = setInterval('window.location.reload()', 5000);
 $('#message').on('keyup change', function(){
    if( $(this).val().length == '' ) {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
        myTimer = setInterval('window.location.reload()', 5000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
 });  

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var messages = document.querySelector('#messages');
  messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight;
});
```

Comment: What changes does that make exactly? It'd still end up refreshing the entire page wouldn't it?

Comment: Change is that you create a NEW interval without ending the first one declared on `var myTimer = setInterval('window.location.reload()', 5000);`

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question for clarity. Please take another look.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the **load** function in jQuery.
all it needs is the container where you want to embed it and the location your pulling your file from.
In this example, you'll just need

```
$("#messages").load('messages.html');
```

The fix to your code

Html here

```html
<div id="messages" class="messages">
<p class="systemnotice center">There are no more messages to load</p>
<br>
<div class="chats"><!-- you need nothing here --></div>
</div>
```

Javascript here

```
//This should be done when page is loaded
setInterval(function(){
  $(".chats").load('./messages.html');
}, 1000)

var myTimer = setInterval('window.location.reload()', 5000);
 $('#message').on('keyup change', function(){
    if( $(this).val().length == '' ) {
        myTimer = setInterval('window.location.reload()', 5000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
 });  

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var messages = document.querySelector('#messages');
  messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight;
});
```

Comment: Could you provide any more complete code because I don't know where this would go.

Comment: With this code it will automatically load messages.html into the page anytime it's updated

Comment: That still refreshes the entire page in the browser, not just the DIV and it no longer scrolls them to the bottom, my initial solution works better than this.

Comment: That doesn't work, the page just shows the no more to load message.